# Java: How to retrieve data from a control statement?

Tags: java

I'm creating an employee time clock for a java class. This portion of my program is for reporting an individual's time, and reporting all employees time. My code works well for the individual, but I'm having trouble converting it to work for all employees. Should I try looping through the whole file and retrieving as it goes? The information being inside a control statement is causing me problems. Also, to only look at a two-week period, would using calendar and date -14 days be a good way to accomplish that?

Any feedback on how to proceed appreciated.

```
package PunchinPunchout;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IDchecker {

    private static BufferedReader br;
    private static BufferedReader br1;
    static int total;
    static int total1;
    

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        getsubject();
       
    }

    public static void getsubject() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> totalhours = new ArrayList<>();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("timeclock1.txt"));
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("newemployee8.txt"));


        String line = "";
        String line1 = "";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an employee ID number: ");
        String idnumber = sc.next();//read the choice
        sc.nextLine();// discard any other data entered on the line

        while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line1.contains(idnumber)) {
                    
                System.out.println("Employee Name & ID ");
                System.out.println(line1);
            }
            
        }

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains(idnumber + " ") && line.contains("in")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("  Date     Time         ID    Punched");
                System.out.println(line);

                String regexp = "[\\s:\\n]+"; // these are my delimiters
                String[] tokens; // here i will save tokens
                
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    tokens = line.split(regexp);
                    total = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                    
                }
                
            } else if (line.contains(idnumber + " ") && line.contains("out")) {

                System.out.println(line);

                String regexp = "[\\s:\\n]+";
                String[] tokens; 
                
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    

                    tokens = line.split(regexp); 
                    total1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);

                    System.out.print("Total hours for " + tokens[0] + " are: ");
                }
                
                int dailytotal = total1 - total;
                System.out.println(dailytotal + " hours"); 
                totalhours.add(dailytotal);
               
            }
           
        }
        System.out.println();
        int sum = totalhours.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        System.out.println("The total hours for the last two weeks is " + sum + " hours.");

    }
}
```

*Output from timeclock1.txt

> 05/05/2014 05:00:00    508     in
>
> 05/05/2014 09:00:00    508 out
>
> 05/05/2014 03:00:00    509     in
>
> 05/05/2014 09:00:00    509 out
>
> 05/05/2014 03:00:00    510     in
>
> 05/05/2014 08:00:00    510 out
>
> 05/05/2014 08:00:00    511     in
>
> 05/05/2014 10:00:00    511 out

*Output from newemployee8.txt

> james  bush    10
>
> bobby  bush    11
>
> john   hunt    12
>
> mick   jag 13
>
> jacob  sanchez 14

Comment: What are the contents of "timeclock1.txt" and "newemployee8.txt"?

Comment: Get rid of the `private static BufferedReader ...`, the `BufferedReader`s don't need to be accessed outside of the methods reading the data.  Create this as local variables.  Use either `try-with-resources` or `try-finally` and close these resources properly.  Once you find a matching employee id, you should be able to use `break` to break out of the loop, as you don't need to continue searching.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Added example of information from those text files.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right, but I won't be searching for the employee ID, I need it to pull each ID one at a time. Can I do this with a slightly different If statement?

Comment: @user3727849 You could use a compound loop, but a better solution would be to load each employee into memory so it's more easily accessiable

Comment: @MadProgrammer And that could be done using an array-list or collection?

Comment: @user3727849 I added an "example" of a way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this a little of an over the top example, but it highlights the power of a OO language like Java...

There are a number of ways that this might be achieved, based on your requirements.  I've made a few assumptions (like a `in` is followed by an `out` for the same employee), but the basic gist is demonstrated.

The intention is centralise some of the functionality into re-usable and manageable blocks, reducing the code duplication.  Access to the data is simplified and because it's done in memory, is faster...

To start with, you will want to create object representations of the employee and time clock data, this will make it easier to manager...

**Employee Example**

```
public class Employee {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public Employee(String text) {
        String[] parts = text.split(" ");
        id = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        name = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

**TimeClockEntry example**

```
public class TimeClockEntry {

    private Date inTime;
    private Date outTime;
    private int employeeID;

    public TimeClockEntry(String text) throws ParseException {
        String parts[] = text.split(" ");
        employeeID = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        setClockTimeFrom(text);
    }

    public void setClockTimeFrom(String text) throws ParseException {
        String parts[] = text.split(" ");
        if ("in".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[3])) {
            inTime = CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
        } else if ("out".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[3])) {
            outTime = CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
        }
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public Date getInTime() {
        return inTime;
    }

    public Date getOutTime() {
        return outTime;
    }

}
```

Now, we need some kind of "manager" to manage the details of these two classes, these managers should provide access methods which allow use to retrieve information that they manage.  These managers will also be responsible for loading the data from the files...

**EmployeeManager example**

```
public class EmployeeManager {

    private Map<Integer, Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeManager() throws IOException {
        employees = new HashMap<>(25);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("NewEmployee8.txt")))) {
            String text = null;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Employee emp = new Employee(text);
                employees.put(emp.getId(), emp);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Employee>(employees.values()));
    }

    public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
        return employees.get(id);
    }

}
```

**TimeClockManager example**

```
public class TimeClockManager {

    private Map<Integer, List<TimeClockEntry>> timeClockEntries;

    public TimeClockManager() throws IOException, ParseException {
        timeClockEntries = new HashMap<>(25);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("TimeClock1.txt")))) {
            String text = null;
            TimeClockEntry entry = null;
            int line = 0;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line % 2 == 0) {
                    entry = new TimeClockEntry(text);
                } else {
                    entry.setClockTimeFrom(text);

                    List<TimeClockEntry> empEntries = timeClockEntries.get(entry.getEmployeeID());
                    if (empEntries == null) {
                        empEntries = new ArrayList<>(25);
                        timeClockEntries.put(entry.getEmployeeID(), empEntries);
                    }

                    empEntries.add(entry);

                }
                line++;

            }
        }
    }

    public List<TimeClockEntry> getByEmployee(Employee emp) {

        List<TimeClockEntry> list = timeClockEntries.get(emp.getId());
        list = list == null ? new ArrayList<>() : list;
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

    }

}
```

Now, internally, these managers are managing the data through the use of `Map`s, to make it easier to find data, specifically, this is most keyed on the employee's id

Now, once we have these, we can ask for information from the as we please...

```
public Report() {
    try {
        EmployeeManager empManager = new EmployeeManager();
        TimeClockManager timeClockManager = new TimeClockManager();

        for (Employee emp : empManager.getEmployees()) {

            System.out.println("[" + emp.getId() + "] " + emp.getName());
            for (TimeClockEntry tce : timeClockManager.getByEmployee(emp)) {
                System.out.println("    "
                        + CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(tce.getInTime())
                        + " to "
                        + CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(tce.getOutTime()));
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException | ParseException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to incorporate both managers into a single class.  The basic idea would be to load the employee and time clock data, the time clock data would become a property of the `Employee` and you could simply be able to access it directly.

This is a slightly more elegant solution, as you have all the data contained within a single construct, but might not meet your needs

**Fully runnable example**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import oracle.jrockit.jfr.parser.ParseException;

public class Report {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Report();
    }

    public Report() {
        try {
            EmployeeManager empManager = new EmployeeManager();
            TimeClockManager timeClockManager = new TimeClockManager();

            for (Employee emp : empManager.getEmployees()) {

                System.out.println("[" + emp.getId() + "] " + emp.getName());
                for (TimeClockEntry tce : timeClockManager.getByEmployee(emp)) {
                    System.out.println("    "
                            + CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(tce.getInTime())
                            + " to "
                            + CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(tce.getOutTime()));
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException | ParseException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeManager {

        private Map<Integer, Employee> employees;

        public EmployeeManager() throws IOException {
            employees = new HashMap<>(25);
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("NewEmployee8.txt")))) {
                String text = null;
                while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        Employee emp = new Employee(text);
                        employees.put(emp.getId(), emp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Employee>(employees.values()));
        }

        public Employee getEmployee(int id) {
            return employees.get(id);
        }

    }

    public class TimeClockManager {

        private Map<Integer, List<TimeClockEntry>> timeClockEntries;

        public TimeClockManager() throws IOException, ParseException {
            timeClockEntries = new HashMap<>(25);
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("TimeClock1.txt")))) {
                String text = null;
                TimeClockEntry entry = null;
                int line = 0;
                while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (!text.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        if (line % 2 == 0) {
                            entry = new TimeClockEntry(text);
                        } else {
                            entry.setClockTimeFrom(text);

                            List<TimeClockEntry> empEntries = timeClockEntries.get(entry.getEmployeeID());
                            if (empEntries == null) {
                                empEntries = new ArrayList<>(25);
                                timeClockEntries.put(entry.getEmployeeID(), empEntries);
                            }

                            empEntries.add(entry);

                        }
                        line++;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public List<TimeClockEntry> getByEmployee(Employee emp) {

            List<TimeClockEntry> list = timeClockEntries.get(emp.getId());

            list = list == null ? new ArrayList<>() : list;

            return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

        }

    }

    public class Employee {

        private final int id;
        private final String name;

        public Employee(String text) {
            System.out.println("[" + text + "]");
            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                System.out.print((int) c + ",");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            String[] parts = text.split("\\s+");
            id = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            name = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

    }

    public static final SimpleDateFormat CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    public static final SimpleDateFormat CLOCK_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public class TimeClockEntry {

        private Date inTime;
        private Date outTime;
        private int employeeID;

        public TimeClockEntry(String text) throws ParseException {
            System.out.println("[" + text + "]");
            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                System.out.print((int) c + ",");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            String parts[] = text.split("\\s+");
            employeeID = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            setClockTimeFrom(text);
        }

        public void setClockTimeFrom(String text) throws ParseException {
            String parts[] = text.split("\\s+");
            if ("in".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[3])) {
                inTime = CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
            } else if ("out".equalsIgnoreCase(parts[3])) {
                outTime = CLOCK_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
            }
        }

        public int getEmployeeID() {
            return employeeID;
        }

        public Date getInTime() {
            return inTime;
        }

        public Date getOutTime() {
            return outTime;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. While this was only one piece, it was an important one. Helped me ace my project.